# How to insert the content of a RadioButton into SQL Server for UWP C#?

Tags: sql-server, uwp, uwp-xaml

How can I insert the Content"Male" into SQL Server and also the Content"Female" of the RadioButton into the table.

```xml
<RadioButton x:Uid="RBVaron" x:Name="radioMale"  Grid.Row="22" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="{StaticResource SmallFontSize}" GroupName="GroupSex" />

<RadioButton x:Uid="RBHembra" x:Name="radioFemale"   Margin="150,-32,0,0"  Grid.Row="22" Grid.Column="0"  FontSize="{StaticResource SmallFontSize}" GroupName="GroupSex"/>
```

code c#  sql Server:

```cs
cmd.Parameters.Add("@petGender", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40).Value = radioMale;
```

The class.cs

```cs
public string  PetGender { get; set; }
```

Comment: What is your question? You've shown some incomplete snippets of code, but not enough to explain where you are stuck.

Comment: I think you want `Value = radioMale.Checked`

Comment: the question is how I can introduce the RadioButton Content into the Sql Server table.
the jam is at the end of the code. **cmd.Parameters.Add("@petGender", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40).Value = radioMale;**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code provided by you, I observed that you didn’t give a value of `Content` property of a `RadioButton` control. So the content of the two `RadioButton` controls is blank. The `radioMale` is the [Name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.name?view=winrt-19041#Windows_UI_Xaml_FrameworkElement_Name) of a `RadioButton` control. You could refer to the `RadioButton` control by this name `radioMale`.

If you want to insert the content of a `RadioButton` into SQL Server, you need to give a content to a `RadioButton` control. Then get the content value by using the `Name` of a `RadioButton` control.

For example:

Set the value of `Content` property of a `RadioButton` control:

```
<RadioButton x:Uid="RBVaron" x:Name="radioMale"  Grid.Row="22" Grid.Column="0"  GroupName="GroupSex" Content="Male"/>
<RadioButton x:Uid="RBHembra" x:Name="radioFemale"   Margin="150,-32,0,0"  Grid.Row="22" Grid.Column="0" GroupName="GroupSex" Content="Female"/>
```

Get the value of `Content` property of a `RadioButton` control and insert it into SQL Server:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@petGender", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40).Value = radioMale.Content;
```

Comment: when I'm going to choose the radiofemale option in the data abyss I introduce radiomale

Comment: the question is whether I have two or more radiobuttons the same group in this case RadioMale and RadioFemale. The value you enter in the table can be one of two petgender options in the Sql statement.